# How to implement Screen Sharing and Controlling for web application (using web sockets)?

Tags: java, websocket, remote-access, remote-desktop, screensharing

The intention is to build a screen controlling/sharing to a web page using web socket.

My question is what is the best way to share a screen (or give control to a screen) (using java or c++ server) to a web socket?

- how to approach that?
- what is the most optimized way to do it? (sending only changing parts of the screen etc etc...)

Using java Robot, I have been able to capture print-screens and create video, one of the challenges I have found is capturing the mouse cursor state, since Java Robot does not draw the mouse cursor in the print screens, for now I will just use the same the cursor image to add it to the print scree.

This post is similar to : 
[How to implement screens sharing for web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14755601/how-to-implement-screens-sharing-for-web-application)

However, that approach does not mention the screen controlling, it only talks about video streaming the screen, so no possible interaction from the clients.