# Screen Sharing through a java website

Tags: java, screensharing

This question may be asked many times. I have a website and I need to integrate a screensharing option in that. There may be multiple people connected and one person will be sharing his screen. Please suggest some good software which can be integrated with a java application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about a Java Web Application, I believe this topicmay be of interest:

- [How to implement screens sharing for web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14755601/how-to-implement-screens-sharing-for-web-application)

Hope it Helps!

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of JrDesktop [api](http://jrdesktop.sourceforge.net/).